# Set VS Code to ignore Pandoc delimiters in HTML template?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pandoc

I'm writing HTML templates for use with Pandoc. I would like all the normal VS Code features for HTML documents like syntax highlighting and linting. [Pandoc templates](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates) use comments like `$--` and other variables or logic like `$foo$` or `${ foo }$`.

I'd like to be able to add Pandoc-style comments inside the `<style>` elements to describe what I am doing for my future self and other developers without using CSS comments that will make it to the final rendered HTML.

When I write something like

```
<style>$-- layout overrides
  @media (min-width: 1536px) {
    .container {
$-- override framework to be more narrow
      max-width: 1200px;
    }
  }
</style>
```

the linter(?) gives messages like `at-rule or selector expected` and highlights things with red squiggly underlines and all that.

I'd love to be able to have the Pandoc lines ignored. It does not seem like I get there there with the [`html.format.unformatted`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_formatting) setting or tools like [VS Code Custom Data](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-custom-data).

Maybe there is something in `Configure 'HTML' language based settings...` that I don't know about, or maybe I have to build my own language server ()?

Comment: you want to be able to modify the AST parser to use an additional syntax, not very likely